# Reactive repository

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I try to create some basic Spring 5 application based on reactive stack (Reactor + WebFlux).

My next goal is to implement reactive repository that is able to:

1. Save Book.
2. Find all Books.

My repository needs to cover following scenario:

Scenario A:

1. No one is subscribed for FindAll
2. Someone saves a book (id = 1)
3. Client1 subscribe for FindAll
4. Book (id=1) is pushed to Client1 (Client1 stays subscribed, stream is not completed!)
5. Someone saves a book (id = 2)
6. Book (id=2) is pushed to Client1 (Client1 stays subscribed, stream is not completed!)

So, IMO this scenario is a mix of Cold and Hot source concepts. Before anyone subscribe we collect a data that someone is saving in our repository in some buffer (lets say normal List). For ALL subscribers that will subscribe for FindAll we need to push buffered List (that was collected before his subscription) and DO NOT complete stream to be allow to push later collection updates.

I was able to achive that but I'm still thinking is there any easier way to do this? Maybe there is a solution in Reactor project that already cover this scenario?

My implementation:

```
public class InMemoryBookRepository {

private final Map<String, Book> bookMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final UnicastProcessor<Book> processor = UnicastProcessor.create();
private final FluxSink<Book> fluxSink = processor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
private final Flux<Book> hotFlux = processor.publish().autoConnect();

@Override
public void save(Book book) {
    bookMap.put(book.getId(), book);
    fluxSink.next(book);
}

@Override
public Flux<Book> findAll() {
    //without fromIterable I cannot push books that where saved before someone subscribed
    return Flux.fromIterable(bookMap.values())
            .concatWith(hotFlux)
            //Unfortunately this solution produces duplicates so we need to filter them
            .distinct();
}
}
```

Ofc, I can't use just Cold publisher- because stream will be completed after publishing collected Books. For the same reason I can't use Hot one because I will miss elements produced before someones subscription.

Side note: in my code I do not have any cleaning mechanism of my map, so it will produce exception at some point but this is not important for now.

Comment: Just wondering why can't you use a reactive databse like mongo?

Comment: Good question. But answer is pretty easy - this repository is part of real system mock. I do not want to add any more components that I need to maintain separately to my applcation just for mock purposes. However if there is any in memory solution of reactive database - I will definitly give it a try. Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple... I don't know why I missed this beautiful operator: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#replay--

So basically remove whole `List/Map` part of the code and use `replay()` instead of `publish()`

Simplified example:

```
UnicastProcessor<String> processor = UnicastProcessor.create();
FluxSink<String> fluxSink = processor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
//change 'publish()' to 'replay()'
Flux<String> hotFlux = processor.publish().autoConnect(); 

hotFlux.subscribe(n -> log.info("1st subscriber: {}", n));

fluxSink.next("one");

hotFlux.subscribe(n -> log.info("2nd subscriber: {}", n));

fluxSink.next("two");
```

Output with `publish()`:

```
1st subscriber: one
1st subscriber: two
2nd subscriber: two
```

Output with `replay()`:

```
1st subscriber: one
2nd subscriber: one
1st subscriber: two
2nd subscriber: two
```